# hardware acceleration for developer non/media type apps?

Tags: video

I'm wondering whether disabling Hardware Acceleration on my card will affect regular web surfing, sql server, and software development. Or is it just video?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "disabling hardware acceleration on your card"? Are you talking about disabling the dedicated video card and just leaving the onboard graphics?

Comment: No - disabling the hardware acceleration feature on the card, as some of my business apps - according to online sources - work better without the accelereation.

Comment: How exactly would you disable hardware acceleration on a card that ultimately provides hardware acceleration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Web browsers are now starting to take advantage of hardware acceleration, such as Firefox 4 and IE 9 (and Flash video), turning it off would impact that. The Aero desktop and WPF apps are also hardware accelerated. I woudn't recommend turning it off, you don't really gain anything, apart from maybe 1W less in electricity usage from the GPU.

Comment: The Dell XPS 15z lasts almost an extra hour while using only the onboard graphics; in the end, it depends on what you want out of the PC.

Comment: Yeah, if you've got a laptop like that with Optimus etc and can turn off the discrete graphics, it will save battery life.